# How to correctly implement security on a websocket session?

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I want to implement an asynchronous mechanism using websockets. 
Here's the idea:

1. The client performs a REST call
2. The server returns a "subscribingID" and starts a background process
3. The client registers as subscriber on this topic (suppose 12232442 is the id):

   ```js
   this.stompClient.subscribe('/callback/12232442', (messageOutput) => {
       let mess = JSON.parse(messageOutput.body);
       console.log(mess);
   });
   ```
4. Once done the server simply sends the message and closes the connection:

   ```js
   stompSession.send("callback/12232442", new MessageOutput());
   ```

It should work but here's the catch: how can I be sure that another client can't simply subscribe to an ID that exists but does not belong to them?

Also, is there any built-in mechanism to achieve this?

Comment: What STOMP broker are you using? Most have security mechanisms built-in for authentication and authorization.

Comment: Using spring boot default broker, then I send messages to a redis cluster with pub/sub

Answer (score 1):

1. When the server receives a REST request for a subscription ID, you can store the newly generated ID in a Subscription HashMap.
2. In order to do processing when a new subscription request comes you can implement a custom `StompEventHandler`, like so

```
@Controller
public class StompEventHandler{
@EventListener
public void handleSubscription(SessionSubscribeEvent event) {
    //Get incoming sessionDetails from event.
    //get the destination.
    // Validate that the destination is present in Subscription HashMap
    // and also that no client maps to the topic id.
    // Based on the result either send the message or send Unauth message to 
       client.

  }
}
```

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/SessionSubscribeEvent.html)

3. Note that you have to store details about session ID of the client as well for this. Instead of broadcasting the message to `/topic/callback/<your_id>`, you would need to send the message to destination like so: `/user/queue/callback/<your_id>`. For sending to a destination as such you would need to use `simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(username, destination, payload, Headers)`
   [Good Read for this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-websockets-send-message-to-user)
4. So since you are sending messages to only a particular session of a particular user, your messages are confidential.
5. If you want to ensure that you do not even have the subscription from the client you can send an `UNSUBSCRIBE` message to the client in the `StompEventHandler` class. This would force unsubscribe the client.
   [Good Read for this](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/issues/36)